# Variadic Templates : Unable to instantiate std types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to instantiate the arguments from the type pack. This allows me to iterate over the types (there are no real arguments involved, but I default instantiate them to be able to iterate over the types by passing the dummy args to another template function)

```
template<typename T>
inline int iterate(T&& dummy) { return T::bar(); }
```

But the problem lies ahead of that, to instantiate the dummy arguments.
It works as expected for base types and pointer types, but not for standard types (I test it with std::string and std::unique_ptr)

This doesn't compile in visual studio 2013 :

```
#include <string>

class A{};

template<typename... Args>
inline void pass(Args&&...) {}

template <class... Args>
void test() { pass(Args()...); }

int main() {
  test<int, int, float, A*, A*>();              // this is fine
  test<int, int, std::string>();                // error C2062:
                                                //   type 'std::string' unexpected
  test<int, int, float, A*, A*, std::string>(); // error C2062: 
                                                //   type 'std::string' unexpected
}
```

Does any one have any pointers, as to the reason ? Is it compiler specific (vs120) ?

However the first problematic call should expand to :

```
pass( int(), int(), std::string() );
```

Which should be fine, no ?

## Workaround

So it seems I've run into the same compiler problem as linked here :
[(Default) construct an object for every variadic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612672/default-construct-an-object-for-every-variadic-type)

I used the same workaround and it now compiles fine :

```
template<typename T> using msvc_identity_fix = T;

template<typename... Args> inline void pass(Args&&...) {}

template <class... Args>
void test() { pass(msvc_identity_fix<Args>()...); }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have included `#include <string>`?